# AWS Firehose newline Character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I've read a lot of similar questions around adding newline characters to firehose, but they're all around adding the newline character to the source.  The problem is that I don't have access to the source, and a third party is piping data to our Kinesis instance and I cannot add the `\n` to the source.

I've tried doing a Firehose data transformation using the following code:

```js
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /* Process the list of records and transform them */
    const output = [];
    event.records.forEach((record) => {
        const results = {
        /* This transformation is the "identity" transformation, the data is left intact */
            recordId: record.recordId,
            result: record.data.event_type === 'alert' ? 'Dropped' : 'Ok',
            data: record.data + '\n'
        };
        output.push(results);
    });
    console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${output.length}.`);
    callback(null, { records: output });
};
```

but the newline is still lost.  I've also tried `JSON.stringify(record.data) + '\n'` but then I get an `Invalid output structure` error.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69360476/703217 it is a solution that does not require code or a Lambda function, it uses the Dynamic Partitioning feature and only works for new Data Streams unfortunately. So if you have an existing shard it won't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try decoding the `record.data`
add a new line
then encode it again as base64.

This is python but the idea is the same

> ```
> for record in event['records']:
>     payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])
>     # Do custom processing on the payload here
>     payload = payload + '\n'
>     output_record = {
>         'recordId': record['recordId'],
>         'result': 'Ok',
>         'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload))
>     }
>     output.append(output_record)
> return {'records': output}
> ```

From the comment of @Matt Westlake:

> For those looking for the Node.js answer, it's
>
> ```js
> const data =
> JSON.parse(new Buffer.from(record.data,'base64').toString('utf8'));
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```js
> new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data) + '\n').toString('base64')
> ```

Comment: For those looking for the node answer, it's 
`const data = JSON.parse(new Buffer.from(record.data,'base64').toString('utf8'));` and `new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data) + '\n').toString('base64')`

Comment: there's a missing space on `newBuffer.from(record.data,'base64')` between `new` and `Buffer`

Comment: From AWS Cloudwatch: 
DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead. [June-2022]

Answer (score 1):

The `kinesis-firehose-cloudwatch-logs-processor` blueprint lambda does this (with some additional handling for cloudwatch logs).

Here's the lambda code from the blueprint as of today:

```
/*
For processing data sent to Firehose by Cloudwatch Logs subscription filters.

Cloudwatch Logs sends to Firehose records that look like this:

{
  "messageType": "DATA_MESSAGE",
  "owner": "123456789012",
  "logGroup": "log_group_name",
  "logStream": "log_stream_name",
  "subscriptionFilters": [
    "subscription_filter_name"
  ],
  "logEvents": [
    {
      "id": "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345",
      "timestamp": 1510109208016,
      "message": "log message 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345",
      "timestamp": 1510109208017,
      "message": "log message 2"
    }
    ...
  ]
}

The data is additionally compressed with GZIP.

The code below will:

1) Gunzip the data
2) Parse the json
3) Set the result to ProcessingFailed for any record whose messageType is not DATA_MESSAGE, thus redirecting them to the
   processing error output. Such records do not contain any log events. You can modify the code to set the result to
   Dropped instead to get rid of these records completely.
4) For records whose messageType is DATA_MESSAGE, extract the individual log events from the logEvents field, and pass
   each one to the transformLogEvent method. You can modify the transformLogEvent method to perform custom
   transformations on the log events.
5) Concatenate the result from (4) together and set the result as the data of the record returned to Firehose. Note that
   this step will not add any delimiters. Delimiters should be appended by the logic within the transformLogEvent
   method.
6) Any additional records which exceed 6MB will be re-ingested back into Firehose.
*/
const zlib = require('zlib');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

/**
 * logEvent has this format:
 *
 * {
 *   "id": "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345",
 *   "timestamp": 1510109208016,
 *   "message": "log message 1"
 * }
 *
 * The default implementation below just extracts the message and appends a newline to it.
 *
 * The result must be returned in a Promise.
 */
function transformLogEvent(logEvent) {
    return Promise.resolve(`${logEvent.message}\n`);
}

function putRecordsToFirehoseStream(streamName, records, client, resolve, reject, attemptsMade, maxAttempts) {
    client.putRecordBatch({
        DeliveryStreamName: streamName,
        Records: records,
    }, (err, data) => {
        const codes = [];
        let failed = [];
        let errMsg = err;

        if (err) {
            failed = records;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.RequestResponses.length; i++) {
                const code = data.RequestResponses[i].ErrorCode;
                if (code) {
                    codes.push(code);
                    failed.push(records[i]);
                }
            }
            errMsg = `Individual error codes: ${codes}`;
        }

        if (failed.length > 0) {
            if (attemptsMade + 1 < maxAttempts) {
                console.log('Some records failed while calling PutRecordBatch, retrying. %s', errMsg);
                putRecordsToFirehoseStream(streamName, failed, client, resolve, reject, attemptsMade + 1, maxAttempts);
            } else {
                reject(`Could not put records after ${maxAttempts} attempts. ${errMsg}`);
            }
        } else {
            resolve('');
        }
    });
}

function putRecordsToKinesisStream(streamName, records, client, resolve, reject, attemptsMade, maxAttempts) {
    client.putRecords({
        StreamName: streamName,
        Records: records,
    }, (err, data) => {
        const codes = [];
        let failed = [];
        let errMsg = err;

        if (err) {
            failed = records;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.Records.length; i++) {
                const code = data.Records[i].ErrorCode;
                if (code) {
                    codes.push(code);
                    failed.push(records[i]);
                }
            }
            errMsg = `Individual error codes: ${codes}`;
        }

        if (failed.length > 0) {
            if (attemptsMade + 1 < maxAttempts) {
                console.log('Some records failed while calling PutRecords, retrying. %s', errMsg);
                putRecordsToKinesisStream(streamName, failed, client, resolve, reject, attemptsMade + 1, maxAttempts);
            } else {
                reject(`Could not put records after ${maxAttempts} attempts. ${errMsg}`);
            }
        } else {
            resolve('');
        }
    });
}

function createReingestionRecord(isSas, originalRecord) {
    if (isSas) {
        return {
            Data: new Buffer(originalRecord.data, 'base64'),
            PartitionKey: originalRecord.kinesisRecordMetadata.partitionKey,
        };
    } else {
        return {
            Data: new Buffer(originalRecord.data, 'base64'),
        };
    }
}


function getReingestionRecord(isSas, reIngestionRecord) {
    if (isSas) {
        return {
            Data: reIngestionRecord.Data,
            PartitionKey: reIngestionRecord.PartitionKey,
        };
    } else {
        return {
            Data: reIngestionRecord.Data,
        };
    }
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    Promise.all(event.records.map(r => {
        const buffer = new Buffer(r.data, 'base64');
        const decompressed = zlib.gunzipSync(buffer);
        const data = JSON.parse(decompressed);
        // CONTROL_MESSAGE are sent by CWL to check if the subscription is reachable.
        // They do not contain actual data.
        if (data.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
            return Promise.resolve({
                recordId: r.recordId,
                result: 'Dropped',
            });
        } else if (data.messageType === 'DATA_MESSAGE') {
            const promises = data.logEvents.map(transformLogEvent);
            return Promise.all(promises)
                .then(transformed => {
                    const payload = transformed.reduce((a, v) => a + v, '');
                    const encoded = new Buffer(payload).toString('base64');
                    return {
                        recordId: r.recordId,
                        result: 'Ok',
                        data: encoded,
                    };
                });
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve({
                recordId: r.recordId,
                result: 'ProcessingFailed',
            });
        }
    })).then(recs => {
        const isSas = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(event, 'sourceKinesisStreamArn');
        const streamARN = isSas ? event.sourceKinesisStreamArn : event.deliveryStreamArn;
        const region = streamARN.split(':')[3];
        const streamName = streamARN.split('/')[1];
        const result = { records: recs };
        let recordsToReingest = [];
        const putRecordBatches = [];
        let totalRecordsToBeReingested = 0;
        const inputDataByRecId = {};
        event.records.forEach(r => inputDataByRecId[r.recordId] = createReingestionRecord(isSas, r));

        let projectedSize = recs.filter(rec => rec.result === 'Ok')
                              .map(r => r.recordId.length + r.data.length)
                              .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        // 6000000 instead of 6291456 to leave ample headroom for the stuff we didn't account for
        for (let idx = 0; idx < event.records.length && projectedSize > 6000000; idx++) {
            const rec = result.records[idx];
            if (rec.result === 'Ok') {
                totalRecordsToBeReingested++;
                recordsToReingest.push(getReingestionRecord(isSas, inputDataByRecId[rec.recordId]));
                projectedSize -= rec.data.length;
                delete rec.data;
                result.records[idx].result = 'Dropped';

                // split out the record batches into multiple groups, 500 records at max per group
                if (recordsToReingest.length === 500) {
                    putRecordBatches.push(recordsToReingest);
                    recordsToReingest = [];
                }
            }
        }

        if (recordsToReingest.length > 0) {
            // add the last batch
            putRecordBatches.push(recordsToReingest);
        }

        if (putRecordBatches.length > 0) {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let recordsReingestedSoFar = 0;
                for (let idx = 0; idx < putRecordBatches.length; idx++) {
                    const recordBatch = putRecordBatches[idx];
                    if (isSas) {
                        const client = new AWS.Kinesis({ region: region });
                        putRecordsToKinesisStream(streamName, recordBatch, client, resolve, reject, 0, 20);
                    } else {
                        const client = new AWS.Firehose({ region: region });
                        putRecordsToFirehoseStream(streamName, recordBatch, client, resolve, reject, 0, 20);
                    }
                    recordsReingestedSoFar += recordBatch.length;
                    console.log('Reingested %s/%s records out of %s in to %s stream', recordsReingestedSoFar, totalRecordsToBeReingested, event.records.length, streamName);
                }
            }).then(
              () => {
                  console.log('Reingested all %s records out of %s in to %s stream', totalRecordsToBeReingested, event.records.length, streamName);
                  callback(null, result);
              },
              failed => {
                  console.log('Failed to reingest records. %s', failed);
                  callback(failed, null);
              });
        } else {
            console.log('No records needed to be reingested.');
            callback(null, result);
        }
    }).catch(ex => {
        console.log('Error: ', ex);
        callback(ex, null);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will solve the problem

```
__Author__ = "Soumil Nitin Shah"
import json
import boto3
import base64


class MyHasher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def get(self):
        keys = str(self.key).encode("UTF-8")
        keys = base64.b64encode(keys)
        keys = keys.decode("UTF-8")
        return keys

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    output = []
    for record in event['records']:

        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])

        """Get the payload from event bridge and just get data attr """""
        serialize_payload = str(json.loads(payload)) + "\n"
        hasherHelper = MyHasher(key=serialize_payload)
        hash = hasherHelper.get()

        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': hash
        }
        print("output_record", output_record)

        output.append(output_record)

    return {'records': output}
```